# my visio2016 did not show me arraows head in using connector while drawing state machine diagram can I use arrow from use case diagram?

Tags: uml, visio

i am making a project for car rental system and drawing UNIFIED MODELING LANGUAGE state  machine diagram with the MS OFFICE visio app 2016 as i am using different composite state according to my car rental system project and for the connection between different state i have to use some arrow but my connector and pointer did not show any arrow head so i used arrows form Unified Modeling Language use case diagram so its make me confused that whether my state diagram is still right or not

Answer (score 0):

Since Visio has no model semantics but just a pure drawing it's completely irrelevant which connector you use unless it has the form `->` (solid line, open arrow to one side where the transition goes).

Only if you're using a UML modeling tool you can distinguish between different connectors since they have a meta-type and various attributes which then controls the rendering. E.g. state transition, control flow and object flow as well as directed associtions look exactly the same. But in a UML model they have different meta-types and are valid only between distinct elements. However, not all UML tools actually check these constraints.

Comment: The arrow between composite and the arrows we are using in use case are almost same in shape but their usage are different so em asking that if I am using arrows from use case shapes it may change actual meaning of my project diagram or not

Comment: Probably you should post pictures of the arrows.